# How to show terms from another taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, query, taxonomy, search, terms

I have a taxonomy problem that I've been trying to solve for days. I'll try to explain it.

I have two taxonomies, '**type of store**' and '**state**' of a post type called '*store*'.
I'm building a search that should display in which states, particular type of store is present. Just like which stores are in a certain chosen state.

In other words, when I choose a type of store, only states that have such stores should appear.

That way I can display the terms of both, but do not separate them.

```
$taxonomies = array('store_type', 'states');
$args = array(
        'taxonomy' => '$taxonomies',
        'hide_empty' => 'true',
        'parent' => 0,
        'tax_query' => array(
                              'relation' => 'AND',
                            ),
       );
```

**Can someone please help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [taxonomy parameters in WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters),
the "Multiple Taxonomy Handling" example does pretty much what you want if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This question solved my problem. Thank you.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158329/adding-a-term-name-from-a-custom-taxonomy-assigned-to-a-post-link-displayed-by-a?rq=1